# Change values of variable with $.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I am trying to make a plugin like code to use it in variable elements but i am stuck in a place. First see the current code

```js
(function($){
                $.fn.dataTable = function(options){
                    var settings = $.extend({
                        color:"red"
                    }, options);
                    return this.css({
                        color:settings.color
                    });
                }
            }(jQuery));
            
            $('p').dataTable({
                color:"blue"
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello</p>
```

In the code above i have successfully used $.extend to change the color when i call the plugin and its working fine **but i am stuck how to change values of variables while calling plugin**.

I tried something this but this is not working

```
(function($){
    $.fn.dataTable = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({
            var showInterval = 10,
            color:"red"
        }, options);
        return this.css({
            color:settings.color
        });
    }
}(jQuery));

$('p').dataTable({
    color:"blue",
    showInterval :20
});
```

I need to change the value of variable `showInterval`

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to do:

```
var settings = $.extend({
    showInterval: 10,
    color:"red"
}, options);`
```

The `$.extend` takes two objects and merges them. All values of the first one will be overwritten by the ones in the second one, if they are there available.